# google activity recognition api not working

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using Google play services for activity recognition to detect various activities like: Still, On Foot etc. But the code works fine on Moto g devices and fails on HTC one. Can you please verify if my approach is correct? Here are the codes:

**My Activity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private PendingIntent pIntent;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(ActivityRecognition.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION");//For filtering
    }


    @Override

    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRecognitionService.class);
        pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        ActivityRecognition.ActivityRecognitionApi.requestActivityUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, 0, pIntent);//0
    }
    /*@Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
    }*/
    //@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    } 
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
```

where as **ActivityRecognitionService** looks like:

```
public class ActivityRecognitionService extends IntentService {
public ActivityRecognitionService() {
        super("My Activity Recognition Service");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if(ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(intent)){
            ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(intent);
            Log.i(TAG, getType(result.getMostProbableActivity().getType()) + "t" + result.getMostProbableActivity().getConfidence());
            /*Intent i = new Intent("ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION");
            i.putExtra("Activity", getType(result.getMostProbableActivity().getType()) );
            i.putExtra("Confidence", result.getMostProbableActivity().getConfidence());
            sendBroadcast(i);*/
            String aType = getType(result.getMostProbableActivity().getType());
            int aConf = result.getMostProbableActivity().getConfidence();
            fileWrite(aType, aConf);
        }
    }

    private String getType(int type){
        if(type == DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN)
            return "Unknown";
        else if(type == DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE)
            return "In Vehicle";
}
```

On HTC i am getting following **message in logcat**: (Although i got similar messages on moto g, but it still detects the activity)

```
09-28 19:09:11.143: W/asset(7697): Copying FileAsset 0x727dbe28 (zip:/data/app/com.example.activityRec-2.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 254736 to make it aligned.
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp; (184)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;' failed
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp; (184)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;' failed
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp; (184)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;' failed
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp; (184)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;' failed
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 21831: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;.zza (ILcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener;)V
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp; (184)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;' failed
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve static method 21829: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;.zza (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: E/dalvikvm(7697): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.enableAutoManage
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 185 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder;
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)
09-28 19:09:11.173: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 134: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
09-28 19:09:11.183: E/dalvikvm(7697): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 188 (Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat$Builder;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
09-28 19:09:11.183: E/dalvikvm(7697): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 185 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
09-28 19:09:11.183: E/dalvikvm(7697): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 185 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;
09-28 19:09:11.183: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 293: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
09-28 19:09:11.193: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)
09-28 19:09:11.193: W/dalvikvm(7697): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp; (184)
09-28 19:09:11.193: W/dalvikvm(7697): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;' failed
09-28 19:09:11.193: W/dalvikvm(7697): VFY: unable to resolve static method 21829: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;.zza (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzlp;
09-28 19:09:11.193: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7697): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 4324038
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066__release_AU ()
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): Build Date: 02/06/14 Thu
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): Local Branch: 
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): Local Patches: NONE
09-28 19:09:11.233: I/Adreno-EGL(7697): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
09-28 19:09:49.563: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7697): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 4324038
09-28 19:11:22.253: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7697): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 4324038
09-28 19:11:23.373: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(7697): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 4324038
```

---

Update
[image: Order and export]

---

update2
**error log**

```
09-29 11:52:13.790: W/asset(10716): Copying FileAsset 0x77fe6e98 (zip:/data/app/com.example.activityRec-1.apk:/resources.arsc) to buffer size 254736 to make it aligned.
09-29 11:52:13.820: W/dalvikvm(10716): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 236: Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;.setLocalOnly (Z)Landroid/app/Notification$Builder;
09-29 11:52:13.830: W/dalvikvm(10716): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 527: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
09-29 11:52:13.830: D/At least(10716): it creats
09-29 11:52:13.840: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(10716): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 8115000 but found 4324038
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:385>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066__release_AU ()
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.06
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): Build Date: 02/06/14 Thu
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): Local Branch: 
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_3.5_RB1.04.04.02.006.066
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): Local Patches: NONE
09-29 11:52:13.880: I/Adreno-EGL(10716): Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
```

**SDK image**
[image: sdk mgr]

Comment: eclipse or android studio?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have missed this part of the support library [setup guide](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

> In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.

The app runs fine on lollipop because it has the classes needed for card views but the older devices don't hence the need for the support lib.

Comment: please see my update, is this the correct jar?, still the only error i get is similar to: Google Play services out of date. Requires 8115000 but found 4324038, which i always get for other phones too.

Comment: Have the first set of errors gone away? Please open the sdk manager from eclipse or using the android app and update the google play services library. YOu might find that the support library etc also might need to be updated. Sometimes you need to close and reopen eclipse and do a project clean and build for the changes to take effect

Comment: yup i did updated already, can you see any bug in my code. Also, quick question for app that is supposed to run on all various version/makes of Android, what should be the target API? I am hoping to get all users ranging from Moto g to S4 (all android versions too), any suggestions on both will be  very helpful